# Play Framework 1.x webfonts CORs issue

Tags: heroku, playframework, cors, playframework-1.x

I am trying to serve webfonts to my website using a CDN (MaxCDN) but am getting the following browser error. Website is hosted on Heroku using Play Framework 1.2.7.2:

> Font from origin 'https://______.netdna-ssl.com' has
>   been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://______.herokuapp.com' is therefore
>   not allowed access.

MaxCDN pointed me to this article but is only relevant for Apache server. Any suggestions on how to fix this for Play Framework 1.2.7.2.

https://www.maxcdn.com/one/tutorial/how-to-use-cdn-with-webfonts/

I can find an article explaining how to resolve the issue for Play 2.x here (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/CorsFilter) but not for Play 1.x.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not related to your Play Framework server but to the CDN one.

You are trying to perform a request from one origin to another (CORs request) : from the page at  'http://______.herokuapp.com' to the CDN at 'https://______.netdna-ssl.com'

When performing this request, the CDN server must add the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response, otherwise it will be blocked by the browser for security reasons.

If you want more informations about CORS you can check [this SO answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work/10636765#10636765)

If you have access to the CDN you can add the rules to add the header, otherwise I suggest that you host the font yourself.

**Update :**

I don't know if it is possible to add headers to requests made to the public folder, but one solution would be to create a dedicated Font controller.
This controller would be used to get the font with the appropriate header.

```
public class Fontextends Controller{

  public static void font(String fontName){
    response.accessControl("*");     //we add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to the response
    renderBinary(new File("public/font/"+fontName));  // we send the font in the response
  }

}
```

Now you need to make sure that MaxCDN is accessing your fonts from the route linked to this action.

Another solution would be to use a Front-end HTTP server like it is described here : https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/production#anameserverFrontendHTTPservera
You should be able to add the headers with this solution but I have never done it so I can't help you.

Comment: The CDN I'm using is MaxCDN and they don't have a way to edit the header according to their support team. They say that they just use whatever the header was on the origin server that they pulled from and so I need to adjust the header for the assets (fonts) there... which would imply changing a Play Framework setting. I can't find any information related to this though for Play! 1.x

Comment: Ok, so I asuume the font are originally hosted on the public folder of play ?

Comment: Will try the solution and mark it correct if it works. Reading it I think it will so thank you!